# Call parent's public member function outside of class

Tags: c++

So here is an example what I would like to do in function `main`.
Example, watch my comment between the lines:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A {
public:
    void msg()
    {
        puts("from A");
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void msg()
    {
        puts("from B");
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;

    a.msg();
    b.msg(); // This must print out B
    b.msg(); // And I want this to print A. What is the syntax for that?
}
```

I do not want add extra code to this, just may be some synthatic sugar. Something like `A::b.msg`, but it did not work

Comment: Use `b.A::msg();`

Comment: What is the *actual* and *original* problem you want to solve by doing something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
b.A::msg(); //will call msg from the class A
```

But maybe you should be looking at a different pattern?